# Access through Facebook application to group or event photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I try to figure out how to access facebook group or event photos/albums. The graph API of the group/event object doesnot have a connection for photo or pictures.

Any other way to access photo and pictures from groups or events - perhaps through FQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/ that would allow you to access an event's photos given the event ID.

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=$eid
```

You can make a similar query for groups. Here are the permissions you would need to get from your user assuming the event/group is not public.

Groups:
user_groups

Events:
user_photo_video_tags

You should not need an access token if the event/group is public.

Comment: hi C, I was able to make it work through the object_id field of the photo_tag table in the FQL Query above. I used this object_id to make a graph API get request for the returned object and this worked very nice. Thanks

Comment: HI Marc, Can you please share your code. i have similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The API does have a connection for getting event photos now, it is [event_id]/photos and needs read_stream permission if the event is public otherwise it also needs user_events or friends_events permission

If you want to get photos of a group check this question: [retrieve photos from a facebook group using the GraphAPI](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4869595/retrieve-photos-from-a-facebook-group-using-the-graphapi)